# Український відповідник "Совпадение? - Не думаю!"

Tags: іншомовні-слова, відповідник

Неодноразово чула, коли україномовні люди у розмові, також у ЗМІ, використовували вислів **"Совпадение? - Не думаю!"**. Наприклад, бачимо це у статті ["Совпадение? - Не думаю!": Російські дипломати покинули Великобританію на літаку, який перевозив підроблений кокаїн з Аргентини](http://patrioty.org.ua/politic/sovpadenye--ne-dumaiu-rosiiski-dyplomaty-pokynuly-velykobrytaniiu-na-litaku-iakyi-perevozyv-pidroblenyi-kokain-z-arhentyny-221740.html) . Неодноразово думала над українським відповідником. Прямий переклад зовсім втрачає звучання. "Збіг?  ([*співпадіння*](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B3/) в укр. мові не вживається) - Не думаю? 
Чи є українські відповідники цього вислову, які б передавали не лише сенс, але й органічно б звучали?

Comment: Тут варто зауважити, що словосполучення — це сталий вислів, мем, який використовується одіозним пропагандистом, і той пропагандист — російськомовний. Будь-який переклад словосполучення втратить звʼязок з автором, що може відірвати від контексту і зруйнувати ідею перекладу як таку.

Comment: А мені теж цікавить близький переклад. Щось на кшталт "Збіг? - Навряд чи!". Якщо вже й писати російськомовну версію то транслітерацією "Совпадєніє? - Нє думаю!". Можливо також є годний український фразеологізм.  Мають також бути норми які регулюють вживання іншомовного тексту без перекладу як частини речення.

Comment: "Збіг? - Не певен!" на мій погляд найбільш "органічно". Однак, я згоден з іншими, що переклад цього сталого виразу треба робити наближеним до оригінала, а не до благозвучності українською мовою.

Answer (score 5):

Знайти влучного українського відповідника до цього вислову не вийде, і я поясню чому.

Перш за все, - це не фразеологізм, цей вислів було сказано російським ведучим, а у наших ЗМІ він вживається як сарказм. Отже якщо бути точним, то це цитата, а хіба ми шукаємо українські відповідники для таких цитат, як, для прикладу, "Veni, vidi, vici"? Ні, найкраще, що ми можемо зробити - це перекласти їх ("Прийшов, побачив, переміг).

Не раз доводилося чути транслітерацію "Совпадєніє - не думаю". Робиться це й для того, щоб створити певну відсилку на Дмитра Кисильова та й на російські ЗМІ та російську пропаганду загалом, а тому, якщо ми замінимо цей вислів українським фразеологізмом (що вкрай важко зробити), то тоді він просто перестане бути алюзією (чого не трапиться у випадку із перекладом, [приклад](http://finenews.info/fajna-narodna-mudrist/fotozhabi/item/16904-spivpadinnia-ne-dumaiu)).